# XML. Just tag ending. What's this?

Tags: xml, tags

If I have a XML file like this one:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<data>
    <tag1>Some information</tag1>
    <tag2/>
</data>
```

Is it a common thing we have just the tag ending (at this case `tag2`)?
This tells we don't have information stored on `tag2` or this is an error on the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `</tag2>` by itself, without a preceding opening `<tag2>`, is an error.

You can have an empty `tag2` but it's written like this:  `<tag2 />`

Comment: Sorry is `<tag2/>` instead of `</tag2>`. Thx. Edited.